# Why hook_update_N() doesn't work?

Tags: 8

I have a custom module already installed, and I am trying to add a new table to the database with `hook_update_N()`. So, I edited `hook_schema()` and `hook_update_N()` in the my_module.install file as below.

```
function my_module_schema() {
  $schema['my_table'] = array(
    'fields' => array(
      'application_setup_id' => array(
        'type' => 'serial',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'description' => 'Primary Key: ID',
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('application_setup_id'),
  );
  return $schema;
}

function my_module_update_8601(&$sandbox) {
  $spec = array(
    'fields' => array(
      'application_setup_id' => array(
        'type' => 'serial',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'description' => 'Primary Key: ID',
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('application_setup_id'),
  );
  $schema = Database::getConnection()->schema();
  $schema->createTable('my_table', $spec);
}
```

I am running `drush updatedb` to update the database after the changes. No database changes are done.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it supposed to be 8601 or 8101? Check the documentation. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/8.2.x

Comment: `drupal_get_installed_schema_version('module_name')` will get you the info you're looking for

Comment: my Drupal version is 8.6.2 when I check in admin/reports/status .I tried changing N to 8001,8101,8201,8701. when I run dpm(drupal_get_installed_schema_version('my_module')); in devel I am getting 8000.

Comment: my module name is using camel case, I changed it to lower case in the function name for hook_update_n and tried still didn't work.

Comment: There sounds like theres a lot wrong here. This is a core function that has worked for many versions, why you can't get it to trigger... I don't think there is enough information here.

Comment: The hook_schema()  function was already present with two tables in my my_module.install file. I needed to add a new table in db, so instead of adding the table in the hook_schema() function and reinstall the module and loose data. I approached hook_update_n function. I am not sure what more information  I need to provide.

Comment: my module name is something like "FC_Munich_form" this. I uninstalled the module. Renamed module name into lowercase "fc_munich" installed without the new table and then tried hook_update_8001. It worked. So, I think the name  of the module should be lowercase is a very important thing. Any ideas to bypass this without uninstalling the module will be appreciated.

Comment: This answer [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36011/hook-update-n-is-not-running?noredirect=1&lq=1) gave me the idea to think in that way.